# fopen with pathname and variable filename not working

Tags: c, linux, fopen, relative-path

I see a few similar questions in C, but they do not answer my question.
 
Consistent perror is   Error: No such file or directory.
User input is aFile.txt and I confirm this file exists in the same directory as the program.
If I manually change:

```
input_file = fopen(path, "r");<br/>
```

to:

```
input_file = fopen(".\aFile.txt", "r");<br/>
```

IT WORKS...
Also, `printf("path = %s\n", path);` prints `.\aFile.txt`
which leads me to believe my concatenation is OK.
What am I doing incorrectly?

```
   char path[25] = "./";
   char filename[21];
   printf("Enter filename, max 20 characters: ");
   fgets(filename, 20, stdin);
   strcat(path, filename);
   strtok(path, "\n"); // FIXED THE ISSUE BY REMOVING THE trailing '\n'
   printf("path = %s\n", path);

   FILE * input_file;
   input_file = fopen(path, "r"); // fopen(".\aFile.txt", "r") works!!!
   if (input_file == NULL)
        perror("Error");
   else {
        loader(list, input_file);
        fclose(input_file);
        printf("list loaded from file succesfully.\n");
   }
```

Comment: Most likely you have the new line character in your path variable (fgets includes it).  Remove trailing whitespace and it should work

Comment: [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."

Comment: Well, certainly is a duplicate... unless you didn't know about the fgets \n issue... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the new line being read.  A good way to see this is to print the filename with a leading and trailing ":":

```
printf("path = :%s:\n", path);
```

What is printed is:

```
Server:junk Username$ ./a.out 
Enter filename, max 20 characters: test.txt
path = :./test.txt
:
Error: No such file or directory
```

Note the second ":" is on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

fgets will include the newline character, so most likely this is what's killing it.  Remove the newline at the end and it should work.